# Using Google One Tap in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-identity

I'd like to use Google One Tap in my Angular 11 app. Following the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/load-one-tap-client-library) I added `<script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"></script>` to my html and then used the following code in my `app.component.html`:

```
<div id="g_id_onload"
    data-client_id="MY_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"
    data-callback="handleCredentialResponse",
    data-cancel_on_tap_outside="false">
</div>
```

The popup works fine, though I can't seem to log in. If I create a function `handleCredentialResponse` in `app.component.ts`, I get the following error: `[GSI_LOGGER]: The value of 'callback' is not a function. Configuration ignored.`

If I instead try to use the JavaScript API, Typescript throws the following error: `Property 'accounts' does not exist on type 'typeof google'`

What should I do to be able to using Google One Tap in Angular?

Comment: Hi Frank! I had the same issue, but I ended up using the Javascript API instead of the HTML one.... Here are some useful links:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69907948/vue-2-gsi-logger-the-value-of-callback-is-not-a-function-configuration-ign

https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference

And you might also need to install `@types/google-one-tap` to get rid of the warnings:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google-one-tap

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem when I used the HTML API approach, so I ended up using the [JavaScript API instead](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference).

Here's what I did:

First, make sure to install the [@types/google-one-tap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google-one-tap) package.

As you mentioned, I'm also importing the script in my `index.html` file, like so:

```
<body>
  <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

Now, moving on to your main component which in my case is `app.component.ts`, import the following first:

`import { CredentialResponse, PromptMomentNotification } from 'google-one-tap';`

Then, you can add this on the `ngOnInit()`. Make sure to read the documentation to get more details on the [onGoogleLibraryLoad](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#onGoogleLibraryLoad) event:

```
// @ts-ignore
window.onGoogleLibraryLoad = () => {
  console.log('Google\'s One-tap sign in script loaded!');

  // @ts-ignore
  google.accounts.id.initialize({
    // Ref: https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#IdConfiguration
    client_id: 'XXXXXXXX',
    callback: this.handleCredentialResponse.bind(this), // Whatever function you want to trigger...
    auto_select: true,
    cancel_on_tap_outside: false
  });

  // OPTIONAL: In my case I want to redirect the user to an specific path.
  // @ts-ignore
  google.accounts.id.prompt((notification: PromptMomentNotification) => {
    console.log('Google prompt event triggered...');

    if (notification.getDismissedReason() === 'credential_returned') {
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['myapp/somewhere'], { replaceUrl: true });
        console.log('Welcome back!');
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Then, the `handleCredentialResponse` function is where you handle the actual response with the user's credential. In my case, I wanted to decode it first. Check this out to get more details on how the credential looks once it has been decoded:  https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#credential

```
handleCredentialResponse(response: CredentialResponse) {
// Decoding  JWT token...
  let decodedToken: any | null = null;
  try {
    decodedToken = JSON.parse(atob(response?.credential.split('.')[1]));
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error while trying to decode token', e);
  }
  console.log('decodedToken', decodedToken);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This saved me tons of time.

Comment: Thumbs up for the library imports. It solved other issues like the `width` and `shape` properties on the `renderButton`

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem in adding the function to the angular component.
Then i found a solution by adding JS function in `appComponent` like this:

```
(window as any).handleCredentialResponse = (response) => {
      /* your code here for handling response.credential */
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Yep. A small hack that does it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

set the div in template to be rendered in ngOnInit

```
    `<div id="loginBtn" > </div>`
```

dynamically inject script tag in your login.ts as follows

```
constructor(private _renderer2: Renderer2, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: Document){}

ngAfterViewInit() {
        const script1 = this._renderer2.createElement('script');
        script1.src = `https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client`;
        script1.async = `true`; 
        script1.defer = `true`; 
    this._renderer2.appendChild(this._document.body, script1);
  }

ngOnInit(): void { 
    // @ts-ignore
    window.onGoogleLibraryLoad = () => {  
      // @ts-ignore
      google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: '335422918527-fd2d9vpim8fpvbcgbv19aiv98hjmo7c5.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        callback: this.googleResponse.bind(this),
        auto_select: false,
        cancel_on_tap_outside: true,  
      })
      // @ts-ignore
      google.accounts!.id.renderButton( document!.getElementById('loginBtn')!, { theme: 'outline', size: 'large', width: 200 } )
      // @ts-ignore
      google.accounts.id.prompt(); 
    }
  }


async googleResponse(response: google.CredentialResponse) { 
        // your logic goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google One Tap js library tries to find `callback` in the global scope and can't find it, because your `callback` function is scoped somewhere inside of your app, so you can attach your callback to window, `like window.callback = function(data) {...}`.
Also, since you are attaching it to window, it's better to give the function a less generic name.