# How to make Google Sign In work with a Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, google-api, vuejs3, google-signin

I can make GSI see the global function to handle sign in success in the Vue single file component code below:

```
<!-- JS ----------------------------------------------------->
<script setup lang="ts">

globalThis.handleSignIn = function(): void
{
    console.log("signed in !");
}
</script>

<!-- HTML ----------------------------------------------------->
<template>
    <div>
        Sign in
    </div>
    <div id="g_id_onload"
        data-client_id="43915.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        data-callback="handleSignIn"
    >
```

But how can I make the Google element see a standard Vue method?

Removing the `globalThis` from the funcion, and setting the HTML attribute to `:data-callback="handleSignIn"` gives the error `[GSI_LOGGER]: The value of 'callback' is not a function`

Comment: I'm not sure, but try adding the colon `:data-callback="handleSignIn"`

Comment: Thanks, but isn't that exactly what I have in my code?

Comment: Oh, I just focus on your code snippet. So, you did make it works. Now you want another way to do it without setting your function to `globalThis`?

Comment: Can you try this solution?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69907948/vue-2-gsi-logger-the-value-of-callback-is-not-a-function-configuration-ign
It worked for me this way :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it.

> npm install --save vue-plugin-load-script@^2.x.x

> npm i @types/google-one-tap

> npm i @types/google.accounts

```
import { loadScript } from "vue-plugin-load-script";
...
type hasGoogle = { [key: string]: any } & { google: typeof import("google-one-tap") };
    export default defineComponent({
      data() {
        return {};
      },
      methods: {
        renderGLogin() {
          (window as hasGoogle).google.accounts.id.initialize({
            client_id: "",
            callback: somefunc(),
            ux_mode: "popup",
          });
          (window as hasGoogle).google.accounts.id.renderButton(
            document.getElementById("buttonDiv")!,
            {
              // customization attributes
              theme: "outline",
              size: "large",
              width: 200,
              type: "standard",
            }
          );
          (window as hasGoogle).google.accounts.id.prompt(); // also display the One Tap dialog
        },
      },
      components: {},
      mounted() {
        loadScript("https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client")
          .then(() => {
            this.renderGLogin();
          })
          .catch(() => {
            console.error("failed loading google, reload.")
          });
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `globalThis` trick was not working for me, and neither was putting the code directly on a component of type script: the inner content was passed to the browser in a sanitized way at first and therefore it would not be detected by the google script. Instead I had to rely on an external js file, where I put my callback function.

#### Vue compontent

```html
<template>
<div>
  <component is="script" src="/js/login.js" />
  <component is="script" src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async />

  <div id="g_id_onload"
    data-callback="handleToken"
...
```

#### login.js

```js
async function handleToken(token) {
  console.log('logging in');
}
```

It's slightly inconvenient, but works nonetheless.